# Simulate mouse click with Jasmine Unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm new to Jasmine and have so far was able to set up a couple of basic tests. What I am now trying to do is to create a test that simulates a mouse click event on an element e.g div, a tag etc

My test should be able to determine whether on click of a link a div container expands - I determine this by it classname.

My source code has an event listener listening for a click events:

```
MYSITE.$("sites.retail.UI.Product").Filter = (function () {

    var STATE = MYSITE.system.BitState;
    var NODE = MYSITE.system.DOM.node;

    function _constructor() {
        var _searchContainer = document.getElementById("filterWidget");
        this.toggle = document.getElementById("filterHeader");
        var _self = this;
        MYSITE.system.event.attach(_searchContainer, "click",
            function (e) {
                if (NODE.hasClassName(e.target, "filterHeader")) {
                    if (!STATE.Manager.isFlagSelected('Global', null, STATE.Flags.Global.ProductListShowRefinements)) {
                        _self.collapse();
                    } else {
                        MYSITE.system.DOM.node.removeClassName(document.getElementById('filterCollapse'), "hide")
                        _self.expand();
                    }
                    e.prevent();
                }
                else if (NODE.hasClassName(e.target, "showMoreCont")) {
                    NODE.addClassName(NODE.getElementsByClassAndTagName(_searchContainer, "searchShowMoreCount", "div")[0], "hide");
                    NODE.removeClassName(NODE.getElementsByClassAndTagName(_searchContainer, "hiddenSearchContent", "div")[0], "hide");
                    e.prevent();
                }
                else if (NODE.hasClassName(e.target, "showLessCont")) {
                    NODE.removeClassName(NODE.getElementsByClassAndTagName(_searchContainer, "searchShowMoreCount", "div")[0], "hide");
                    NODE.addClassName(NODE.getElementsByClassAndTagName(_searchContainer, "hiddenSearchContent", "div")[0], "hide");
                    e.prevent();
                }
            }
        );



        _constructor.base.constructor.call(this, document.getElementById("filterWidget"), STATE.Manager.isFlagSelected('Global', null, STATE.Flags.Global.ProductListShowRefinements));
        return this;
    }
    _constructor.extend(MYSITE.UI.Collapse);

    _constructor.prototype.collapse = function (settings) {
        this.toggle.className = "filterHeader closed"; //Set explicitly rather than addNew
        STATE.Manager.setFlag('Global', null, parseInt(STATE.Flags.Global.ProductListShowRefinements));
        _constructor.base.collapse.call(this, { steps: '1' });
    }
```

and HTML markup is

```
<div id="filterWidget">
<a class="filterHeader closed" id="filterHeader" href="#">
<span class="filterHeader">Refine your search</span>
</a>
<div class="collapsible" id="filterCollapse">
<div class="content">
</div></div></div>
```

The unit test I am attempting is:

```
describe("Filter", function() {

    it("should use collapse function", function() {
        loadFixtures('fixture.html');
        var filter = new MYSITE.sites.retail.UI.Product.Filter();

        jQuery.noConflict();
        var btn = jQuery("#filterHeader");
        var click = jQuery.Event('click');
        btn.trigger(click);

        expect(filter.toggle.className).toEqual("filterHeader open");
    });

});
```

But the click event never seems to be picked up by the source code.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: found the answer use the createevent and initevent methods: var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initEvent("click", true, false);

        toggleBtn.dispatchEvent(e);

Answer (score 2):

jquery's `trigger` method neither creates a real event on browser nor calls event handlers registered with core js methods like `addEventListener`!

There is a project at github that is used by the jquery team when testing involves native browser events and here is the plugin: https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate

The idea is that a real event will ultimately call a jquery handler when it will start flowing and the bonus is that even other kind of handlers registered without jquery will respond too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an event triggered by query doesn't have a target object by default. Try this:

```
var click = jQuery.Event("click", { target: $('<div class="">test</div>') });
```

Comment: thanks the issue I am having is that the source code does not pick up the click event. If I bind a click listener in the "it" block of the Jasmine spec this picks up the click event. So click is correctly fired but code does not pick it up, Any ideas - is this a jasmine limitation?

Comment: hi @Andreas, I'd like to trigger 'mouseenter' in my unit test but not luck! can I add target for this event? do you have any document about this? thank!

Comment: I think you can simply trigger the event on the element like this `$el.trigger('mouseenter')`. This should behave like a normal event. If not, just open a new question.